# проверка всех делителей числа на python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая задача - определить, делится ли первое число a на все простые множители второго числа b. Например: solve (15,12) = False, потому что 15 не делится на все простые множители 12 (включая 2). Я дошел до ммомента, когда знаю кто делители `a` и `b`.

Но как сделать проверку для всех элементов сразу а не по одному как у меня? У меня выходит `True` и `False` на каждый элемент, а должно только один раз или то или другое. Спасибо

```
def solve(a, b):
    for i in range(1,b+1):
        if b % i == 0:
            b_div = set([i]) #  1 3 5 15
            if a % i == 0:
                a_div = set([i]) # 1 2 3 4 6 12

    if b_div.issubset(a_div):
        return True
    else:
        return False
print(solve(15,12))
```

Comment: В `b_div` не бывает больше одного элемента. Тут ошибка.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если имеется в виду, что просто на простые делители числа `b`, а не на их произведение, то без поиска простых множителей можно сделать следующее

1. вычисляем `НОД(a, b)`
2. итерационно вычисляем `НОД(b / НОД, НОД)`
3. если в конце НОД будет равен 1, и `b` будет равно 1 - условие выполнено

код:

```
import math

a = 15
b = 12

gcd = math.gcd(a, b)
b //= gcd

while gcd != 1:
    gcd = math.gcd(b, gcd)
    b //= gcd

print("SUCCESS" if b == 1 else "FALSE")
```

быстро, дешево и сердито :)

**P.S.** подумал, что до цикла `b //= gcd` можно и не делать было - просто в цикле на 1 шаг будет больше, зато кода на 1 строчку меньше :)

Comment: спасиб Вам! Можете посоветовать как прокачать  мозги на решение задач. В какую сторону можно посмотреть еще, кроме `codewars`. Знаю про `hackerrank` & `leetcode`, первая вроде тоже хороший ресурс, а 2 чисто для интервью. Спасибо

Comment: Прокачаться на решении задач - простой делайте задачи :) можно для себя и полезные для вас, чтобы изучать особенности питона на мелких задачах - можно ставить перед собой цели типа 1) сделать самый быстрый код 2) сделать самый короткий код и т.д. В любом случае не надо делать что-то ради самоцели. Вот честно признают из всего вами перечисленного ни о чем не слышал :(

Comment: @Zhihtar, спасибо большое еще раз! эту задачку взял отсюда, если будет интересно: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59ec2d112332430ce9000005

Comment: Очень красивое решение.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы уже получили все простые делители для обоих чисел, то дальше можно воспользоваться методом [`set.issubset()` (или перегруженным для **множеств** оператором `<=`)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Пример:

```
In [208]: a_div = set([3, 5])

In [209]: b_div = set([2, 3])

In [210]: res = a_div <= b_div

In [211]: res
Out[211]: False
```

пример использования метода `set.issubset()`:

```
In [212]: {2,3}.issubset([2,3,5,7])
Out[212]: True
```

Comment: сделал так, но все равно не принимает. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем дело. Обновил код. Спасибо

Comment: @user9085541, эта проверка должна быть после того, как вы получили все простые делители для обоих чисел. Не понимаю почему вы поместили ее в цикл...

Comment: еще раз обновил, но тоже самое

Comment: @user9085541, а вы проверили после работы цикла - правильные ли у вас делители в переменных `a_div`, `b_div` ? В вопросе вы утверждали, что с делителями у вас все OK.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо подкорректировать последовательность. Вот пример как получилось у меня:

```
def solve(a,b):
    is_prime = lambda n,i=2: is_prime(n,i+1) if i*i<=n and n%i else i*i>n
    for i in range(2,b+1):
        if b % i == 0 and is_prime(i) and a % i:
            return False
    return True
```

В цикле проверяем в первом условии делитель, во втором его простоту и в третьем делимость первого числа. Если второе или третье условие не выполняются возвращаем False.

**UPD**

для решения на codewars можно попробовать так:

```
from gmpy2 import is_prime

def solve(a,b):
    for i in range(2,b+1):
        if b % i == 0 and is_prime(i) and a % i:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: он мне ошибку дал; `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`

Comment: @user9085541 какие были числа на входе?

Comment: задача с сайта codewars: там такие вводятся 2,256

Comment: @user9085541 на codewars ограничение глубины рекурсии. добавил в ответ код специально для codewars

Comment: к сожалению без изменений

Comment: @user9085541 дайте ссылку на ката

Comment: вот, пожалуйста: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59ec2d112332430ce9000005

Comment: Нашел ошибку, теперь все тесты проходят. Судя по другим решениям, эта задача больше на математику а не программирование. Особенно понравилось это `a**10 % b == 0` :}}